# How can you use a LINQ Lambda Where Property Count = Something

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have an Entity object, Item, that looks like this..

```
public class Item()
{
    IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

and I am trying to get a list of items that have a 0 count

```
var unassigned = db.Items.Where(i => i.Categories.Count() == 0);
```

or

```
var unassigned = db.Items.Where(i => i.Categories.Any());
```

but both throw the error...
"The specified type member 'Categories' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

What is this error telling me and how can I query for what I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `Category` an entity as well that is tracked by EF? EF doesn't seem to think it is. Are you using POCOs? Typically navigation properties that are 1-to-many need to be represented with `ICollection<T>` not IEnumerable.

Basically EF is saying it doesn't know how to turn `db.Items.Where(i => i.Categories.Count() == 0)` into SQL, because it's unsure what Categories is in relation to the database.

It's also possible you will need to `Include("Categories")` on the EF call, but I think you have more fundamental problems than this.

Comment: You are right. Looks like the property is coming from a partial class and not actually in the EDMX.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var unassigned = db.Items.Categories.Where(c=>c.Count() ==0);
```